PySpark dataframes not matching the headers
I have a bunch of parquet files written over a period of 6 months, partitioned by the date and hour when they were created. Over these 6 months, the headers have changed, so the data schema for the parquet files created on Jan 1 is different from the files created on May 1.
I'm trying to read the parquet files created on Jan 1 using PySpark into dataframes (hour by hour), then write them back into parquet files in another folder with a larger block size. The problem is when I compare the headers of the newly created parquet files with that of the original parquet files, they are different.
Here's what I have:
# Code to read into dataframes and write to parquet files
df = spark.read.parquet("original_folder/")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("all_records")
df1 = spark.sql("select * from all_records where datestr='20240101' and hourstr = '0'")
df1.coalesce(80).write.mode("append").partitionBy("datestr","hourstr").option("parquet.block.size", 134217728).parquet("new_folder/")

# Code to read from original parquet file
df_orig = spark.read.parquet("original_folder/datestr=20240101/hourstr=0/")

The headers in df1 and df_orig are different, even for the exact record. Why is that, and how can I extract the actual data with the correct schema from the parquet files?

What do you mean with header? The colum names?

In df/df1 you are reading from a the parent directory. This means that the subfolder names (that are partitioned) are added into the DataFrame as columns. So the names of the subfolders before the = character are used as column names. In this example datestr and hourstr will be added as columns to the DataFrame.
In df_orig you are reading only one partition in a subfolder directory. So the resulting columns of datestr and hourstr are not added to the DataFrame.
This might be an explanation for your difference in the resulting schema.

The difference in the schema was not with the datestr and hourstr though. df/df1/df_orig all did not have the datestr and hourstr columns. It was the other columns that differ. As I mentioned, the columns differ as the schema as changed over time. It seems like df1 have the columns from an earlier time, though the data itself was written more recently and thus, has a different schema. I'm not sure why the columns of df1 was taken from the older schema and not the one that the data was actually written with.
